# Irreducible representations of $M_n(\mathbb C)$ as a real algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

The algebra $M_n(\mathbb C)$ over $\mathbb C$ has unique up to equivalence irreducbile representation: $(r(A))(x)=Ax$ for $A\in M_n(\mathbb C)$, $x=(x_1,...,x_n)^T$, $x_1,...,x_n\in \mathbb C$. 
What are irreducible representation of $M_n(\mathbb C)$ as algebra over $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Exactly the same. I mean the irreducible module you wrote down is still irreducible if you think of $M_n(\Bbb C)$ as an algebra over the reals or indeed just as a ring.

Comment: Even for $n = 1$ ,$\mathbb{C}$ is a $2$-dimensional algebra over $\mathbb{R}.$  This tells you what to do : $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ has a $2n$-dimensional representaton over $\mathbb{R}.$ Given an $n \times n$ matrixover $\mathbb{C},$ say  $A= [a_{rs} + ib_{rs}],$ form a $2n \times 2n$ real matrix ${\hat A}$ by replacing $a_{rs}+ib_{rs}$ by the real $2 \times 2$-matrix $\left(\begin{array}{clcr} a_{rs} & b_{rs}\\-b_{rs} & a_{rs}\end{array}\right).$